# Tricky issue with nested loop printing using C# and PrintDocument for WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, printdocument

I am working on a function in my C# WinForms application that lets me print warehouse pick orders to a PrintDocument, like so:

[image: Sample pick order]

I am using the following c# code to generate this:

```
        private void pdPick_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev) {

            pdPick.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            pdPick.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins ( 50, 50, 50, 50 );
            pdPick.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins ( 50, 50, 50, 50 );

            float yPos;
            count = 0;
            int leftMargin = (int)ev.MarginBounds.Left;
            int rightMargin = (int)ev.MarginBounds.Right;   
            int topMargin = (int)ev.MarginBounds.Top;
            int bottomMargin = (int)ev.MarginBounds.Bottom;
            float linesPerPage;
            bool moreRecs = true;
            int lPos;

            // If this is the first page, print a report header
            if (pageCounter == 1) {
                /* PRINT A REPORT HEADER HERE */
            }
            else {      // if this is a subsequent page, print an abbreviated header
                /* PRINT A PAGE HEADER HERE */
            }
            linesPerPage = ( ev.MarginBounds.Height - yPos ) / ( printFont.GetHeight ( ev.Graphics ) + 3 );

            // Cycle through items
            while ( curCount < boxCount && count < linesPerPage ) {
                // PRINT ITEM DETAIL INFO FIRST...

                // Now we cycle through the pick bins for the item...

                foreach (PickItem record in pickItems) {
                                    /*
                     * 
                     * The issue is that I need to check inside this loop to see if I hit the bottom of the page, 
                     * and if so, I need to start a new page and continue printing whatever remains inside this loop.
                     * 
                     * 
                     */
                }
                
                yPos += 10;
                count++;
                curCount++;
                moreRecs = count < boxItems.Count;
                if ( moreRecs ) {
                    pageCounter++;
                    ev.HasMorePages = true;
                }
                else {
            
                    pageCounter = 1;
                    curCount = 0;
                    yPos += headerFont.Height + 10;
                    ev.HasMorePages = false;
                    return;
                }
            } 
        }
```

**EDIT**
I stripped out the printing details to clarify the issue and address comments about refactoring.

The problem is this:  As you can see from the code, there are two loops to the print sequence.  The first loop obtains a list of products in the pick order, from which I print the title, UPC code, and total units to pick for that item.
**Inside** that loop is *another* loop where I fetch the list of locations to pick the item from, so there could be multiple locations from which product needs to be retrieved to complete that line item.
Now, everything works great as long as I don't go beyond one page.
The challenge is this.  Obviously I need to do a page break if I have more products that will fit within one page.  The problem is, I need to check where I am in the page inside the second loop too, and if so, I need to start a new page and pick up where I left off.  For example, with the third product in the list as shown in the included screenshot, if I print the first bin location and then run out of page room, I need to eject the page, print a new page header, then resume printing the rest of the bin locations for that product, then continue with any remaining products in the order.

From everything I can find, I can't simply do a `ev.HasMorePages=true;` inside that inner loop, because that would cause the entire print sequence to begin again, and that isn't what I want - it would just result in an infinite loop.  I have not been able to find any examples or SO posts on printing to a PrintDocument with nested loops.

Can anyone help me understand how to resolve this?

Comment: Looks like this code is overdue a serious refactor. I'd strongly recommend re-factoring and then editing in the updated code so we can understand it faster. Else ignore me :p

Comment: You need to prepare the full report (I mean a list of something) as if there is no paging at all. And on the second step to break it into pages.

Comment: Printing in C# doesn't really give you that option.  Everything in the printing lifecycle occurs inside the PrintPage event of the document.  Logically you would set HasMorePages=true in order to go to the next page of the document, which simply calls the PrintPage event again, and in this case that would create an infinite loop because it would reload the list of bin locations for the current product.  I need to be able to break out of the page and start a new one from within the inner loop if I run out of page space while printing the list of bin locations.

Comment: I agree with the first comment. Refactor, heavily. The goal should be a separation of concern(s). Encapsulate all the "nasty" technical details of printing "a thing" or "another thing" (like "a header", or "an abbr. header", "a product item", etc...) in a class that also takes care of page management (page numbers, page breaks, etc...). The printing stuff should not be concerned of (a) how many different "things" have to be printed, nor where those "things" come from. This is a different concern for another method or class that uses the aforementioned printing class...

Comment: I appreciate the comments on refactoring, and yes, I could create functions to contain the printing details, but it still doesn't address the fundamental issue of what I am asking.  The outermost loop, cycling through products in the order, is easy to handle for going to the next page.  The trick is how to do the same thing for the inner loop.  Simply calling ev.HasMorePages doesn't work because it just creates an infinite loop problem.

Comment: I appreciate that, but are there any examples of how this might work in the context of printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be a tricky issue if you have the `PickItem` objects of each group *queued* for printing. In this case, all what you need to do:

1. Print the current group and *enqueue* its items in a class field of type [`Queue<PickItem>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.Queue%25601)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue).
2. Loop the queue to print each item and *dequeue* it from the collection while the `Y` position remains within the `MarginBounds`.
3. While drawing the groups and items, request a new page if the `Y` position plus the fixed/variable line height (your lines/rows calculations for the groups and items) exceeds the `e.MarginBounds.Bottom` value.

**Example**

```cs
public partial class SomeForm : Form
{
    private readonly Queue<PickItem> pickItemsQueue;
    private int pageNumber;
    private int curGroup;

    public SomeForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    
        pickItemsQueue = new Queue<PickItem>();
        pdPick.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        pdPick.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(50, 50, 50, 50);
        pdPick.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(50, 50, 50, 50);
    }

    private void PrintCaller()
    {
        pageNumber = 0;
        curGroup = 0;
        pickItemsQueue.Clear();
        using (var d = new PrintPreviewDialog())
        {
            d.Document = pdPick;
            d.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }

    private void pdPick_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        var lineHeight = (int)Font.GetHeight(e.Graphics) + 10;
        int ypos = e.MarginBounds.Y;

        pageNumber++;

        // If this is the first page, print a report header
        if (pageNumber == 1) {
            /* PRINT A REPORT HEADER HERE */
        }
        else {      
            // if this is a subsequent page, print an abbreviated header
        }

        while (curGroup < groups.Count)
        {
            if (ypos + lineHeight > e.MarginBounds.Bottom)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = true;
                return;
            }                

            if (!pickItemsQueue.Any())
            {
                // PRINT ITEM DETAIL INFO FIRST...
                // Adjust the ypos as you like...
                ypos += lineHeight;

                // Create a new queue or add the pickItems to the current instance...
                pickItemsQueue = new Queue<PickItem>(pickItems);
            }

            while (pickItemsQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                if (ypos + lineHeight > e.MarginBounds.Bottom)
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    return;
                }

                var item = pickItemsQueue.Dequeue();

                // Print it and update the ypos...

                ypos += lineHeight;
            }

            curGroup++;
        }
    }
}
```